# How might I obtain a Snapshot or Thumbnail of a web page using PHP?

Tags: php, screenshot, html, thumbnails

I need to create Snapshots / Thumbshots / Site preview a-site.com.

There are some site as thumbshot.org that meets with I need. But I do not want to use an external service, not to depend on others for my project (What would happen if they close the site?)

For this reason, I am looking for some project to let me do this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in the PHP library to do this - you're looking at setting up an external application (with a queue) to take images, although you can of course use PHP to add items to the queue.

There are a couple of Windows functions in GD that takes screen shots of the computer (webserver - not the client) so perhaps you could write a script in PHP to do this.

**Edit:** Was thinking of these: [`imagegrabscreen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php) and [`imagegrabwindow`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php). I'm not sure they will do what you want however (even in full screen mode Firefox has  ablue bar at the top of the screen - not sure about other browsers). However, [Pierre has something](http://blog.thepimp.net/archives/Screen-capture-with-PHP-and-GD.html) on these functions if you're interested.

I'd suggest writing an application in another language (I assume .NET has something) to do this for you.
**Edit:** [This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006053603/http://bobpowell.net/capture.aspx) tells you how to do it in C#

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can use GD's [`imagegrabwindow()`](http://www.php.net/imagegrabwindow) function.

Edit: The help page actually shows you how to grab a screenshot from IE.

Comment: Thanks.
At least now I have an idea where to go.
I did not know that function.
I will try to make a script that generates the snap and go through automatically tftp

Answer (score 0):

There's not much PHP would do for you in this situation. You'd need a complete (X)HTML rendering engine with CSS-support, possibly also with JavaScript support.

That, or use some kind of kinky script that would launch a real browser, and take a screenshot out of that. Either way, PHP is probably not the right tool for the operational part.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Firefox extension that converts the webpage you're viewing to an image:

http://www.screengrab.org/

http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146

If you're willing to get creative, it might be possible to access this problematically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
I found a pseudo-solution, (using dcom + imagegrabscreen + wamp).
I need to resize the final.png with gd, because the png is equal to resolution of client (in my home, is a picture of 1650*1280).
Whe I end this, I will post a .zip file to dowload
Thanks again
(But if anyone have a better idea, I am happy to see that)

PS: Sorry for my english