# How can I generate a screenshot of a webpage using a server-side script?

Tags: php, python, screenshot, server-side-scripting

I need a server-side script (PHP, Python) to capture a webpage to a PNG, JPG, Tiff, GIF image and resize them to a thumbnail.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

#### See also:

> - [Web Page Screenshots with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686858/web-page-screenshots-with-php)
> - [How can I take a screenshot of a website with PHP and GD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627301/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-with-php-and-gd)
> - [How might I obtain a Snapshot or Thumbnail of a web page using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443837)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can probably write something similar to [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/), unless your server already runs Mac OS X.

**UPDATE:** I just saw the link to its Linux equivalent: [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/)

See also:

- [Create screenshots of a web page using Python and QtWebKit](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/)
- [Taking automated webpage screenshots with embedded Mozilla](http://www.hackdiary.com/2004/06/13/taking-automated-webpage-screenshots-with-embedded-mozilla/)

Comment: webkit2png can be compiled from source - works without problems on Linux as well (tested on Ubuntu 10.04 x64)

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197219/433718  wkhtml2image shall be the best (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list)

Answer (score 7):

What needs to happen is for a program to render the page and then take an image of the page. This is a very slow and heavy process but it [can be done in PHP on Windows.](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php)

Also check the comments in the documentation article.

For python [I'd recommend reading this article](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/). It highlights some of the solutions.

There are services you can also call (via some API) that will return you an image. But usually they cost ([WebShots](http://webshotspro.com/) for example)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to:

- read the webpage and all the its multimedia content (images, flash, etc)
- utilize a browser rendering engine to render the webpage
- take a screenshot and save it as image

first and third steps are easy, the second step is more challenging ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php, you could use imagegrabscreen (PHP 5 >= 5.2.2). Imagegrabscreen: captures the whole screen.