# Django thumbnails from urls

Tags: python, thumbnails

I have this [Wordpress.com site](http://wpthemes1.wordpress.com/) with thumbnails of themes. I thought about creating a similar site with Django. Instead of using the thumbnail images from the Wordpress gallery as in the page above, I want to have thumbnails of actual blogs. Is there a way to display thumbnails from urls?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing django-related here, consider this question
[How can I take a screenshot/image of a website using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-to-get-a-website-screenshot-in-python)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed the tags. I was hoping for something simpler than discussed in the link; but that doesn't seem to be possible.