# Django - Generating Image from HTML

Tags: python, django

I am quite comfortable in generating PDFs from HTML using pisa. Is there any similar option to generate image instead of PDF? The purpose is to generate dynamic Identity cards.

Comment: The HTML -> PDF transformation is non-trivial -- there's a lot of layout stuff etc. going on. Why not just convert your PDFs to images?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390493/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-section-of-a-web-page-from-the-shell) should be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pisa` does a lot of layout, formatting and what have you. Why not just convert the PDFs you already have to images?

You can use something like [ImageMagick's Python bindings](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php?ImageMagick=fbfpsck20jomf7iut3ob9urjh2#python).