# Simple way to capture a webpage screenshot using python

Tags: python, linux, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a website screenshot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-to-get-a-website-screenshot-in-python)

"Simple way to capture a webpage screenshot using python!"

I have google'd a little for the subject, but can't find anything useful ...

I need a way to capture screenshots of websites with a Python script from a Debian "server" Linux (no X) .. how is that possible? Is there a simple way?

Comment: possibile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-to-get-a-website-screenshot-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/

> Oh, wait! QWebPage depends an QtGui, and QtGui depends on a running X server (at least on Unix systems). So how
>   can we make use of this on a headless server machine? The answer is **Xvfb**, a framebuffer based X server, originally designed for testing purposes. Of course, it requires some X-libs and fonts, too (how should a page be rendered without any fonts?), but it does not have so much overhead like the real XOrg-server and don’t need to be running all the time. Just call the script this way: