# How to download image using requests

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

I'm trying to download and save an image from the web using python's `requests` module.

Here is the (working) code I used:

```
img = urllib2.urlopen(settings.STATICMAP_URL.format(**data))
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(img.read())
```

Here is the new (non-working) code using `requests`:

```
r = requests.get(settings.STATICMAP_URL.format(**data))
if r.status_code == 200:
    img = r.raw.read()
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(img)
```

Can you help me on what attribute from the response to use from `requests`?

Comment: to use r.raw you need to set stream=True

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download large file in python with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)

Answer (score 653, accepted):

You can either use the [`response.raw` file object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raw), or iterate over the response.

To use the `response.raw` file-like object will not, by default, decode compressed responses (with GZIP or deflate). You can force it to decompress for you anyway by setting the `decode_content` attribute to `True` (`requests` sets it to `False` to control decoding itself). You can then use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to have Python stream the data to a file object:

```
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get(settings.STATICMAP_URL.format(**data), stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

To iterate over the response use a loop; iterating like this ensures that data is decompressed by this stage:

```
r = requests.get(settings.STATICMAP_URL.format(**data), stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r:
            f.write(chunk)
```

This'll read the data in 128 byte chunks; if you feel another chunk size works better, use the [`Response.iter_content()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) with a custom chunk size:

```
r = requests.get(settings.STATICMAP_URL.format(**data), stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

Note that you need to open the destination file in binary mode to ensure python doesn't try and translate newlines for you. We also set `stream=True` so that `requests` doesn't download the whole image into memory first.

Comment: With the help of your answer I could able to find data in text file, steps I used are `r2 = requests.post(r.url, data); print r2.content`. But now I also want to know `filename`. is their any cleaned way? -- presently I found file name in header -- `r2.headers['content-disposition']`  that gives me output as: `'attachment; filename=DELS36532G290115.csi'`  I am parsing this string for filename... is their any cleaner way?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: yes, the `content-disposition` header is the way to go here; use [`cgi.parse_header()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_header) to parse it and get the parameters; `params = cgi.parse_header(r2.headers['content-disposition'])[1]` then `params['filename']`.

Comment: To get the default 128 byte chunks, you need to [iterate over the `requests.Response` itself](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L613): `for chunk in r: ...`. Calling `iter_content()` without a `chunk_size` will [iterate in 1 byte chunks](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L642).

Comment: @dtk: thanks, I'll update the answer. Iteration [changed after I posted my answer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/2ac391373329b2d8c67d34fd7c056ff9db16a5f9).

Comment: Wouldn't be much pertinent to use `r.ok` instead of `r.status_code == 200` to check for a valid http code

Comment: @KumZ two reasons: `response.ok` was never documented, and it produces true for any 1xx, 2xx or 3xx status, but only a 200 response has a response body.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: to support non-ascii filenames, you could use [`rfc6266-parser` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rfc6266-parser/): `rfc6266.parse_requests_response(r).filename_unsafe` (it uses `url` if the filename can't be extracted from `Content-Disposition`).

Answer (score 300):

Get a file-like object from the request and copy it to a file. This will also avoid reading the whole thing into memory at once.

```
import shutil

import requests

url = 'http://example.com/img.png'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```

Comment: Thank you so much for coming back and answering this. Though the other answer is works, this one is leaps and bounds simpler

Comment: It's worth noting that few servers are set to GZIP their images because images already have their own compression. It's counterproductive, wastes CPU cycles with little benefit. So while this may be an issue with text content, specifically with images it's not.

Comment: is there any way we can access the original filename

Comment: @phette23 It's also worth noting that Google PageSpeed reports and does that by default.

Comment: Should set `r.raw.decode_content = True` before `shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)` because `by default, decode compressed responses (with GZIP or deflate)`, so you will get a zero-file image.

Comment: @SiminJie When you write `r.raw.decode_content` do you mean `response.raw.decode_content`?

Comment: Nice answer, but I'd add `if response == 200` before writing to file

Answer (score 238):

How about this, a quick solution.

```
import requests

url = "http://craphound.com/images/1006884_2adf8fc7.jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("/Users/apple/Desktop/sample.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: what do you mean with ! `f = open("/Users/apple/Desktop/sample.jpg", 'wb')` what do you mean with this path !? i want to download image

Comment: That opens a file descriptor in the path specified to which the image file can be written.

Comment: @AndrewGlazkov I think it would be more Pythonic to use `if response.ok:`

Comment: response.ok is True for any 1xx, 2xx or 3xx status, but only a 200 response has a response body as @Martijn Pieters mentioned in the comments above

Answer (score 91):

I have the same need for downloading images using requests. I first tried the answer of Martijn Pieters, and it works well. But when I did a profile on this simple function, I found that it uses so many function calls compared to `urllib` and `urllib2`.

I then tried the [way recommended](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=binary%20response%20content#binary-response-content) by the author of requests module:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
# python2.x, use this instead  
# from StringIO import StringIO
# for python3.x,
from io import StringIO

r = requests.get('https://example.com/image.jpg')
i = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
```

This much more reduced the number of function calls, thus speeded up my application.
Here is the code of my profiler and the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import profile

def testRequest():
    image_name = 'test1.jpg'
    url = 'http://example.com/image.jpg'

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content():
            f.write(chunk)

def testRequest2():
    image_name = 'test2.jpg'
    url = 'http://example.com/image.jpg'

    r = requests.get(url)
    
    i = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
    i.save(image_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile.run('testUrllib()')
    profile.run('testUrllib2()')
    profile.run('testRequest()')
```

The result for `testRequest`:

```
343080 function calls (343068 primitive calls) in 2.580 seconds
```

And the result for `testRequest2`:

```
3129 function calls (3105 primitive calls) in 0.024 seconds
```

Comment: This is because you've not specified the `chunk_size` parameter which defaults to 1, so `iter_content` is iterating over the result stream 1 byte at a time. See the documentation http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_content.

Comment: This also loads the whole response into memory, which you may want to avoid. There is no to use `PIL` here either, just `with open(image_name, 'wb') as outfile: outfile.write(r.content)` is enough.

Comment: `PIL` is also not in the standard library making this a bit less portable.

Comment: @ZhenyiZhang `iter_content` is slow because your `chunk_size` is too small, if you increase it to 100k it will be much faster.

Comment: This is the best answer. It isn't always best to read the file into memory, but OP specified "images" meaning the files will usually be less than 4MB, thus having a trivial impact on memory.

Comment: It appears that `from StringIO import StringIO`, is now `from io import BytesIO` according to the requests author `http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content`

Answer (score 74):

This might be easier than using `requests`. This is the only time I'll ever suggest not using `requests` to do HTTP stuff.

Two liner using `urllib`:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```

---

There is also a nice Python module named `wget` that is pretty easy to use. Found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget).

This demonstrates the simplicity of the design:

```
>>> import wget
>>> url = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
>>> filename = wget.download(url)
100% [................................................] 3841532 / 3841532>
>> filename
'razorback.mp3'
```

Enjoy.

**Edit:** You can also add an `out` parameter to specify a path.

```
>>> out_filepath = <output_filepath>    
>>> filename = wget.download(url, out=out_filepath)
```

Comment: I used `wget` without any hassles. Thanks for stating the benefits of using `urllib3`

Comment: Note that this answer is for Python 2. For Python 3 you need to do `urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://example.com", "file.ext")`.

Comment: Thanks @Husky. Updated.

Comment: Can we compress image size here ? @Blairg23

Comment: @Faiyaj No, this is just `wget`, there is no compression of files.

Comment: In PyCharm I has to do `import urllib.request`. With `import urllib` it gave the error `Cannot find reference 'request' in '__init__.pyi'`. `import urllib` did work in the console though.

Answer (score 42):

Following code snippet downloads a file.

The file is saved with its filename as in specified url.

```
import requests

url = "http://example.com/image.jpg"
filename = url.split("/")[-1]
r = requests.get(url, timeout=0.5)

if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 25):

There are 2 main ways:

1. Using `.content` (simplest/official) (see [Zhenyi Zhang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108000/167897)):

   ```
   import io  # Note: io.BytesIO is StringIO.StringIO on Python2.
   import requests

   r = requests.get('http://lorempixel.com/400/200')
   r.raise_for_status()
   with io.BytesIO(r.content) as f:
       with Image.open(f) as img:
           img.show()
   ```
2. Using `.raw` (see [Martijn Pieters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/167897)):

   ```
   import requests

   r = requests.get('http://lorempixel.com/400/200', stream=True)
   r.raise_for_status()
   r.raw.decode_content = True  # Required to decompress gzip/deflate compressed responses.
   with PIL.Image.open(r.raw) as img:
       img.show()
   r.close()  # Safety when stream=True ensure the connection is released.
   ```

Timing both shows no noticeable difference.

Comment: I tried a bunch of answers, and your `1.` answer (using `io.BytesIO` and `Image`) was the first one that worked for me on Python 3.6.  Don't forget `from PIL import Image` (and `pip install Pillow`).

Comment: What's different between .content and .raw?

Answer (score 19):

As easy as to import Image and requests

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream = True).raw)
img.save('img1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

Summarizing the great answers from others.

| Method | Needs `requests` | Needs PIL | Needs ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `requests.get` -> `shutil` | Yes | No | - |
| `requests.get` -> `open(mode="wb")` | Yes | No | - |
| `requests.get` -> `ByteIO` -> `Image.save` | Yes | Yes | - |
| `urllib` | - | - | - |
| `wget` | No | No | `wget` |
| `requests.get` -> `PIL.Image` -> `np.save` | Yes | Yes | `numpy` |

---

#### Use `shutil` and output the decoded raw content from `requests.get`

Original answer modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/610569

```
import shutil
import requests

img_url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/dpreview.jpg'

response = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)        
with open('dpreview.jpg', 'wb') as fout:
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, fout)
```

#### Writing the binary directly into file I/O

```
import requests

img_url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/dpreview.jpg'

response = requests.get(img_url, stream=True) 

with open('dpreview.jpg', 'wb') as fout:
    for chunk in response:
        fout.write(chunk)
```

#### Stream content into `io.BytesIO` into `PIL.Image` object and save it

```
from io import BytesIO

import requests
from PIL import Image

img_url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/dpreview.jpg'

# Stream to BytesIO
response = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.save('dpreview.jpg')


# Using raw content
response = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
img = Image.open(response.raw)
img.save('dpreview.jpg')
```

#### Use `urllib`

Original answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33866125/610569

```
import urllib

img_url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/dpreview.jpg'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, "dpreview.jpg")
```

And if a specific user-agent is needed for the request, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69764951/610569

```
import urllib

opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

img_url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/dpreview.jpg'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, "dpreview.jpg")
```

#### Use `wget`

```
import wget

img_url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/dpreview.jpg'

wget.download(img_url, out='dpreview.jpg')
```

#### Saving `PIL.Image` as `numpy` array

```
import requests
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np


img_url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/dpreview.jpg'

response = requests.get(img_url, stream=True) 
img = Image.open(response.raw)

# Converts and save image into numpy array.
np.save('dpreview.npy', np.asarray(img))

# Loads a npy file to Image
img_arr = np.load('dpreview.npy')
img = Image.fromarray(img_arr.astype(np.uint8))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I did it

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = 'your_url'
files = {'file': ("C:/Users/shadow/Downloads/black.jpeg", open('C:/Users/shadow/Downloads/black.jpeg', 'rb'),'image/jpg')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)

img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more user-friendly answer that still uses streaming.

Just define these functions and call `getImage()`. It will use the same file name as the url and write to the current directory by default, but both can be changed.

```
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

def createFilename(url, name, folder):
    dotSplit = url.split('.')
    if name == None:
        # use the same as the url
        slashSplit = dotSplit[-2].split('/')
        name = slashSplit[-1]
    ext = dotSplit[-1]
    file = '{}{}.{}'.format(folder, name, ext)
    return file

def getImage(url, name=None, folder='./'):
    file = createFilename(url, name, folder)
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        for block in r.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break
            f.write(block)

def getImageFast(url, name=None, folder='./'):
    file = createFilename(url, name, folder)
    r = requests.get(url)
    i = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
    i.save(file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Uses Less Memory
    getImage('http://www.example.com/image.jpg')
    # Faster
    getImageFast('http://www.example.com/image.jpg')
```

The `request` guts of `getImage()` are based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14114741/130427) and the guts of `getImageFast()` are based on the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108000/130427).

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to post an answer as I don't have enough rep to make a comment, but with wget as posted by Blairg23, you can also provide an out parameter for the path.

```
 wget.download(url, out=path)
```

Answer (score 5):

my approach was to use response.content (blob) and save to the file in binary mode

```py
img_blob = requests.get(url, timeout=5).content
with open(destination + '/' + title, 'wb') as img_file:
     img_file.write(img_blob)
```

Check out my [python project](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/download_images) that downloads images from unsplash.com based on keywords.

Answer (score 4):

This is the first response that comes up for google searches on how to download a binary file with requests. In case you need to download an arbitrary file with requests, you can use:

```
import requests
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/lab-data-collections/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
open('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', 'wb').write(requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True).content)
```

Comment: Nice! It has even an implicit `.close()`. This is the best answer as of 2019 I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import requests
import random

url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1308881/pexels-photo-1308881.jpeg? auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
name=random.randrange(1,1000)
filename=str(name)+".jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code.ok:
   with open(filename,'w') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [Blairg23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33866125/15164646) that using `urllib.request.urlretrieve` is one of the easiest solutions.

One note I want to point out here. Sometimes it won't download anything because the request was sent via script (bot), and if you want to parse images from Google images or other search engines, you need to pass `user-agent` to request `headers` first, and then download the image, otherwise, the request will be blocked and it will throw an error.

Pass `user-agent` and download image:

```py
opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, 'image_name.jpg')
```

[Code in the online IDE that scrapes and downloads images from Google images](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-and-Download-Google-Images-with-Python#bs4_original_images.py) using `requests`, `bs4`, `urllib.requests`.

---

Alternatively, if your goal is to scrape images from search engines like Google, Bing, Yahoo!, DuckDuckGo (and other search engines), then you can use [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/). It's a paid API with a free plan.

The biggest difference is that there's no need to figure out how to bypass blocks from search engines or how to extract certain parts from the HTML or JavaScript since it's already done for the end-user.

Example code to integrate:

```py
import os, urllib.request
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "pexels cat",
  "tbm": "isch"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

# download images 
for index, image in enumerate(results['images_results']):

    # print(f'Downloading {index} image...')
    
    opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582')]
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    # saves original res image to the SerpApi_Images folder and add index to the end of file name
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image['original'], f'SerpApi_Images/original_size_img_{index}.jpg')

-----------
'''
]
  # other images
  {
    "position": 100, # 100 image
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQK62dIkDjNCvEgmGU6GGFZcpVWwX-p3FsYSg&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "homewardboundnj.org",
    "title": "pexels-helena-lopes-1931367 - Homeward Bound Pet Adoption Center",
    "link": "https://homewardboundnj.org/upcoming-event/black-cat-appreciation-day/pexels-helena-lopes-1931367/",
    "original": "https://homewardboundnj.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/pexels-helena-lopes-1931367.jpg",
    "is_product": false
  }
]
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is a very simple code**

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("https://i.imgur.com/ExdKOOz.png") ## Making a variable to get image.

file = open("sample_image.png", "wb") ## Creates the file for image
file.write(response.content) ## Saves file content
file.close()
```

Answer (score -3):

for download Image

```
import requests
Picture_request = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: It would be great if everything was that simple. Unfortunately, the code in your example doesn't save image.  It can open the image and that's it.