# urllib2 download HTML file

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

Using `urllib2` in Python 2.7.4, I can readily download an Excel file:

```
output_file = 'excel.xls'
url = 'http://www.nbmg.unr.edu/geothermal/GEOTHERM-30Jun11.xls'
file(output_file, 'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

This results in the expected file that I can use as I wish.

However, trying to download just an HTML file gives me an empty file:

```
output_file = 'webpage.html'
url = 'http://www.nbmg.unr.edu/geothermal/mapfiles/nvgeowel.html'
file(output_file, 'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

I had the same results using `urllib`. There must be something simple I'm missing or don't understand. How do I download an HTML file from a URL? Why doesn't my code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to download files or simply save a webpage you can use urlretrieve(from urllib library)instead of use read and write.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.nbmg.unr.edu/geothermal/mapfiles/nvgeowel.html","doc.html")
#urllib.urlretrieve("url","save as..")
```

If you need to set a timeout you have to put it at the start of your file:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(25)
#seconds
```

Comment: If you can expan on this, it would be an answer. Right now it looks like it should be a comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks, I had used this previously with the same problem, but having it confirmed as correct is useful. I think I'm having issues with overwriting existing files rather than the downloading part.

Comment: I tested it overwriting an existing file and it works fine. You can try to download the file in a temporal folder. If you are using ubuntu you can do it in /tmp/ .

Answer (score 1):

It also Python 2.7.4 in my OS X 10.9, and the codes work well on it.

So I think there maybe other problems prevent its working. Can you open "http://www.nbmg.unr.edu/geothermal/GEOTHERM-30Jun11.xls" in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly answer the question, but if you're working with HTTP and have sufficient privileges to install python packages, I'd really recommend doing this with 'requests'. There's a related answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/45698