# Python: Requests Session Login Cookies

Tags: python, http, cookies, authentication, python-requests

My intention is to log into a site and then access a protected image from a python script. I have both legal and working access from a browser.

This is what I have now.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

s.get('*domain*')

r_login  =s.post('*domain*/user.php', headers={'cmd': 'login', 'loginname': '***', 'password': '***' })

print (s.cookies)
print (r_login.status_code)

r_img = s.get('*domain*/*protectedimage*.jpg')
print (r_img.status_code)
print (r.cookies)

print (s.cookies['PHPSESSID'])
```

Output:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie PHPSESSID=664b0842085b847a04d415a22e013ad8 for *domain*/>]>
200
403
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
664b0842085b847a04d415a22e013ad8
```

I am sure I can successfully log in, because I have once downloaded the html file after doing so, and it was in a form of being logged in. But my problem is that it seems to me that my `PHPSESSID` cookie does not pass so I get a `403` error back. But I clearly have it in my session. I have also tried adding the cookie manually to my `"r_img"` line, and it made no difference, I still get an empty `CookieJar` and a `403` error back. Would this be not possible with only the requests modul? Did I overlook something? Excuse me for being not quite familiar with `HTTP` requests.

I'm using Python 3.4 just for sake of clarity.

Comment: Most probably you should not be setting cookies, but POST data. Cookies would be set by the server your are posting to. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing in your *form data* as *HTTP headers*. A POST login form should send form elements as the `data` parameter instead:

```
r_login = s.post('*domain*/user.php', 
                 data={'cmd': 'login', 'loginname': '***', 'password': '***' })
```

Do *inspect the returned body*, not just the status code. Your POST request was accepted by the server (`200 OK`) but since no login information was posted, the *body* will most likely tell you something like "login incorrect, please try again".

The server most likely cleared the cookie again seeing as it was not a valid login session when you requested the image. The 403 response probably contains a `Set-Cookie` header for `PHPSESSID` with a date in the past to clear it.

Comment: Works wonderful! Thank you very much. I did not know that about post methods. All I had to do is just change the word "headers" to "data". :)

Now I am able to download my image.

_file = open('myimg.jpg', 'wb')
file.write(r_img.content)
file.close()_

Comment: @Tigris: to download (larger) images, consider streaming the download so as not to store the whole download in memory first. See [How to download image using requests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13137817)

Comment: Thanks again. Fortunately I had to only get some small images. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it like this:

As per [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) docs:

```
payload = {'cmd': 'login', 'loginname': '***', 'password': '***'}
url = '*domain*/user.php'
s.post(url, data=payload)
```

Comment: Thanks, sticking more strictly to the documentation would have been one solution.

Comment: @Tigris could you please elaborate why did you accept Martjin's answer and not mine? We have the exact same code and I answered 5 minutes before him.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I did not consider the time at deciding which to choose, I both marked your answers helpful, but Martjin also provided me with the detailed explanation. I really needed to know that a POST method must be sent in a "data" parameter, that bit solved my problem.