# Python: Download a protected image using Requests Session

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to access a protected image on a website. If I use my broswer and log in, I can easily see the image. Now I'm trying to do the same using python.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260149/python-requests-session-login-cookies) which seemed like the same issue that I have. With that I wrote the following program:

```
import requests     

session = requests.Session()
session.get("https://www.page.com/login")
response = session.post("https://www.page.com/login", data = {"cmd": "login", "username": "myusername", "password": "mypass"})

print response.text
```

Output here is:

```
{"status":"ok","message":"Successful login.","referer":"https:\/\/page.com\/"}
```

I've also saved the `response.text` into a .html file, which confirmed that I've logged in. If at this point I open any subpage on page.com, I'm still logged in.

Then I try to access the protected image at `url`:

```
with open('image.html', 'wb') as file:
    response = session.get(url, headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    print response.status_code
    file.write(response.text)
file.close()
```

Which gives the output of `403`. If I open the `image.html` file there's an "Item not available".

I've tried doing all of this using `mechanize` and `cookielib` instead of `requests.Session()` where I created a cookiejar, created a `Browser()` object, successfully logged in but as I tried accessing that image, I had the same 403 error. Therefore any ideas will be greatly appriciated.