# Saving json response in python

Tags: python, json, pycurl

I am using this code do get information from my website with python, and this works like a charm, but can i save this output to a variable or at least to a json or txt file

```
import pycurl
def getUserData():
   c = pycurl.Curl()
   c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://api.github.com/users/braitsch')
   c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json'])
   c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 0)
   c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'username:userpass')
   c.perform()
getUserData()
```

Comment: Why are you using `pycurl` here, if I may ask? There are probably better options, like [`requests`](http://python-requests.org/).

Comment: ah i am new to python and this is what i found working when i googled for curl and python

Comment: requests worked excellent, thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use curl here; Python comes with batteries included, albeit with an API that is only marginally better than `pycurl`.

I recommend you install [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) rather than try and make `urllib2` and passwords work:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/users/braitsch'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
auth = ('username', 'userpass')
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=auth)

with open('outputfile.json', 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write(response.content)
```

If the response is large, you can stream the content to a file, see [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests/13137873#13137873), the same techniques would apply here.

Comment: @jpthesolver2 note that this answer also references `urllib2`, so it is *aimed at Python 2*, where `response.content` is a string, not a `bytes` value. Since this is writing out JSON here, using `wb` is not really necessary in that case. Still, it doesn't do harm either and with `wb` the code works in Python 3 as well, so thanks for that.