# How to download image to memory using python requests?

Tags: python, image, memory

Like here [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests) , but  to memory, using http://docs.python-requests.org.

Comment: `request.get('http://...').content`

Comment: Just use ```StringIO``` instead of opened file object and you can use answer you provided.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. cStringIO.StringIO(opened_session.get("url").content)

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following code, the image data will be set in `img`, not a file in the disk, than you can manipulate it with opencv.

```
import io
import requests
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
url = 'http://example.com/img.jpg'
data = requests.get(url).content
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```