# How to convert curl -F command into python code with requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am developing with apis however I faced with a problem that I have never met.

```
curl -F "media=@IMAGE_NAME" 'xxxx url'
```

How do I convert it into python code with requests?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests

Comment: @Ajay Thanks but this is my ture means of this problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

```
files = { 'media': open(image_name, 'rb') }
```

Then

```
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

see
http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Answer (score 2):

There's a [great example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) of a POST request in the manual. I think yours specifically would be:

```
r = requests.post("xxx url", data={"media": "@IMAGE_NAME"})
```

Comment: Yes, I've known this usage. Actually I am not understanding what @IMAGE_NAME means.  In a web app, Does it mean the file itself or the file name I got from the form?

Comment: Sorry, I have ready known that files = { 'media': open(image_name, 'rb') }

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `-F` parameters you can either use a tuple:

```
requests.post("https://www.example.com", data=[("foo", "bar"), ("baz", "off")])
```

or a dict:

```
requests.post("https://www.example.com", data={"key1": "bar", "baz": "off"})
```

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests show some examples.

Answer (score -1):

As per your case :

```
def command_string_generator(method, token, port, account,container=None, obj=None, headers_in=None, curlhead=None):
    url = 'xxxx url'
    image = "media=@IMAGE_NAME"
    command_string = 'curl -F %s %s ' % (image ,url)
    print command_string
    return command_string
```

you can use a function like this as per your needs with -F and change accordingly. Hope  this might be helpful.Additional parameters are just for convienience.

Comment: Thanks for your answering but I want to use the requests :p

Comment: Hahaaaa. Sure your choice. :)