# Why is it necessary to use a stream to download an image through HTTP GET?

Tags: python, python-requests, shutil

Here is a body of code that works, taken from:     https://stackoverflow.com/a/18043472

It uses the requests module in python to download an image.

```
import requests, shutil

url = 'http://example.com/img.png'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```

Two questions I've been thinking about:

1) Why is it necessary to set stream=True? (I've tested it without that parameter and the image is blank) Conceptually, I don't understand what a streaming GET request is.

2) What's the difference between a raw response and a response? (Why is shutil.copyfileobj necessary, why can't I just directly write to file?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quote from documentation:

> If you set stream to True when making a request, Requests cannot
>   release the    connection back to the pool unless you consume all the
>   data or call Response.close.

More info [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/).

Comment: Why am I unable to download an image without using a stream? What's the difference between using it and not using it?

Comment: It should ensure that you can get the whole resource you request for, but it can lead to inefficiency with connections.