# Download and save PDF file with Python requests module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to download a PDF file from a website and save it to disk. My attempts either fail with encoding errors or result in blank PDFs.

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: url = 'http://www.hrecos.org//images/Data/forweb/HRTVBSH.Metadata.pdf'

In [3]: response = requests.get(url)

In [4]: with open('/tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
   ...:     f.write(response.text)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4be915a4f032> in <module>()
      1 with open('/tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
----> 2     f.write(response.text)
      3 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-14: ordinal not in range(128)

In [5]: import codecs

In [6]: with codecs.open('/tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb', encoding='utf8') as f:
   ...:     f.write(response.text)
   ...:
```

I know it is a codec problem of some kind but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You should use `response.content` in this case:

```
with open('/tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

From [the document](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

> You can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:
>
> ```
> >>> r.content
> b'[{"repository":{"open_issues":0,"url":"https://github.com/...
> ```

So that means: `response.text` return the output as a string object, use it when you're downloading a **text file**. Such as HTML file, etc.

And `response.content` return the output as bytes object, use it when you're downloading a **binary file**. Such as PDF file, audio file, image, etc.

---

[You can also use `response.raw` instead](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content). However, use it when the file which you're about to download is large. Below is a basic example which you can also find in the document:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.hrecos.org//images/Data/forweb/HRTVBSH.Metadata.pdf'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('/tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

`chunk_size` is the chunk size which you want to use. If you set it as `2000`, then requests will download that file the first `2000` bytes, write them into the file, and do this again, again and again, unless it finished.

So this can save your RAM. But I'd prefer use `response.content` instead in this case since your file is small. As you can see use `response.raw` is complex.

---

Relates:

- [How to download large file in python with requests.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py)
- [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Comment: Cool, thank you for the additional information about response.raw.

Answer (score 50):

In Python 3, I find pathlib is the easiest way to do this. Request's *response.content* marries up nicely with pathlib's write_bytes.

```
from pathlib import Path
import requests
filename = Path('metadata.pdf')
url = 'http://www.hrecos.org//images/Data/forweb/HRTVBSH.Metadata.pdf'
response = requests.get(url)
filename.write_bytes(response.content)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. The original question was Python 2.7 but I've moved on and now use Python 3. I didn't know about about the pathlib library [new in version 3.4] and will incorporate it into my current projects.

Comment: It give `544` and the file is broken, any ideas?

Answer (score 34):

You can use urllib:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "filename.pdf")
```

Comment: This is best one, tbh.

Comment: This one is best

Comment: `urlretrieve` relies on global settings to determine request headers, making it unsuitable for some use cases.

Comment: This one is really good. One thing to keep in mind is that without `headers` it might throw a 403 error. To avoid it, [pass `user-agent` into `headers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511429/15164646).

Answer (score 4):

Please note I'm a beginner. If My solution is wrong, please feel free to correct and/or let me know. I may learn something new too.

My solution:

**Change the downloadPath accordingly**  to where you want your file to be saved. Feel free to use the absolute path too for your usage.

Save the below as downloadFile.py.

Usage: `python downloadFile.py url-of-the-file-to-download new-file-name.extension`

**Remember to add an extension!**

Example usage: `python downloadFile.py http://www.google.co.uk google.html`

```
import requests
import sys
import os

def downloadFile(url, fileName):
    with open(fileName, "wb") as file:
        response = requests.get(url)
        file.write(response.content)


scriptPath = sys.path[0]
downloadPath = os.path.join(scriptPath, '../Downloads/')
url = sys.argv[1]
fileName = sys.argv[2]      
print('path of the script: ' + scriptPath)
print('downloading file to: ' + downloadPath)
downloadFile(url, downloadPath + fileName)
print('file downloaded...')
print('exiting program...')
```

Comment: Pawel, thank you for your answer. I was a Python novice when I first posted this question. Now I know the language very well. Your use case of writing a Python script to download a file from a command line can be covered by utilities like wget or curl. Also, your function downloadFile as posted seems to call itself. Did you intend to indent the second block of code? In stackoverflow you can correct that by out-denting that. I'd also like to suggest you have a look at Python's argparse library. You can use it to make nice command line utilities. It will take care of the parameters for you.

Comment: I do like your use of a context manager (with open... as file:, etc) to handle the file writing. Your code is neatly written. You are on a good path to learning Python. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Jim!  I've edited the post, and indeed I did not "intend to indent" :D the main part of the program. Thanks for your advices! :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this should work in Python3:

```
import urllib.request 
..
urllib.request.get(url)
```

Remember that urllib and urllib2 don't work properly after Python2.

If in some mysterious cases requests don't work (happened with me), you can also try using

```
wget.download(url)
```

Related:

Here's a decent explanation/solution to find and download all pdf files on a webpage:

https://medium.com/@dementorwriter/notesdownloader-use-web-scraping-to-download-all-pdfs-with-python-511ea9f55e48

Answer (score -5):

regarding Kevin answer to write in a folder `tmp`, it should be like this:

```
with open('./tmp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

he forgot `.` before the address and of-course your folder `tmp` should have been created already

Comment: 1- Kevin did not come up with the idea to write in `tmp`, it was like like in OP's question. 2- the `/tmp` directory is the tmp in Unix systems, located at `/tmp`, no `.`