# How to download pdf files using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, download, downloading-website-files

I was looking for a way to download pdf files in python, and I saw answers on other questions recommending the urllib module. I tried to download a pdf file using it, but when I try to open the downloaded file, a message shows up saying that the file cannot be opened.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGL5t.png)

This is the code I used-

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_s11_qp_42.pdf", "9709_s11_qp_42.pdf")
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, the file automatically saves to the directory my python file is in. How do I change the location to which it gets saved?

Edit-
I tried again with the link to a sample pdf, http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf

The code is working with this link, so why won't it work for the other one?

Comment: You can use `requests` for this task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module

Comment: @DavidZemens I won't call it a duplicate. The OP is concerned about his solution not working rather than finding a different one.

Comment: When I go to that url I first get a captcha (by cloudflare) to prove that I'm not a robot and only then can access the pdf. Also cloudflare sites often restrict access based on user agent. If you open the file in a text editor you'll probably find html there instead of a pdf.

Comment: You didn't actually download a PDF from that URL - you downloaded the CAPTCHA form needed to access the PDF.

Comment: So is there any way i can download files like that??

Comment: You'd probably need to complete the captcha in a browser, take the cookies that were set and user agent from the browser and use those in your request. That may work for a while, but you may be presented with a new captcha after some time.

Comment: @mata uhh how would you do that lmao

Comment: If you use the above mentioned [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) module, sending [cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) and a custom [user agent](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) should be easy. Where to find them depends on your browser.

Comment: Try a crawler, you will need tostar session on the website

Answer (score 13):

Try this. It works.

```
import requests
url='https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c029/baf196f33050ceea9ecbf90f054fd5654277.pdf'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('C:/Users/MICRO HARD/myfile.pdf', 'wb') as f:
f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: When I attempt to open the saved file, I get:
"Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'D:/myfile.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type of because the file has been damaged..."

Comment: Turns out this code does work. The PDF at the url in the code above happens to be corrupt. Pointing it to the PDF I wanted worked fine

Answer (score 2):

You can also use wget to download pdfs via a link:

```
import wget

wget.download(link)
```

Here's a guide about how to search & download all pdf files from a webpage in one go: https://medium.com/the-innovation/notesdownloader-use-web-scraping-to-download-all-pdfs-with-python-511ea9f55e48

Answer (score 0):

- You can't download the pdf content from the given url using
  `requests` or `urllib`.
- Because initially the given url was pointed to another web page after that
  only it loads the pdf.
- If you have doubt save the response as html instead of pdf.
- You need to use headless browsers like `panthomJS` to download files
  from these kind of web pages.

Comment: How would a headless browser be of any use in this case? You still need to complete the captcha, which you can't do in a headless browser.