# Create URL to download a file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, url, download

So I will create a PDF/HTML that will be stored in a directory and I have to create a URL that will allow the user to download this file and send this URL.

This has to be done in Python 2.7.x

Comment: Please check the answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module).

Comment: Okay. so this talks about downloading a particular file using a URL in Python. I want to create and store a file on a machine and create a URL to that file , and be able to send this URL to the client as a response so that they can download it. Hope this makes it clearer.