# Download a pdf embedded in webpage using python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I want to download the pdf and store it in a folder on my local computer.
Following is the link of pdf i want to download https://ascopubs.org/doi/pdfdirect/10.1200/JCO.2018.77.8738

I have written code in both python selenium and using urllib but both failed to download.

```
import time, urllib
time.sleep(2)
pdfPath = "https://ascopubs.org/doi/pdfdirect/10.1200/JCO.2018.77.8738"
pdfName = "jco.2018.77.8738.pdf"
f = open(pdfName, 'wb')
f.write(urllib.urlopen(pdfPath).read())
f.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download and save PDF file with Python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: I saw that answer, Made this since my URL doesn't have filename ending with extension '.pdf' So i was trying more of selenium python implementations.

Comment: I just use your information is given and, with given link and file name to be, just used a solution written there and added a link there  and problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier with requests

```
import requests 

url = 'https://ascopubs.org/doi/pdfdirect/10.1200/JCO.2018.77.8738'
pdfName = "./jco.2018.77.8738.pdf"
r = requests.get(url)

with open(pdfName, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pathlib import Path
import requests
filename = Path("jco.2018.77.8738.pdf")
url = "https://ascopubs.org/doi/pdfdirect/10.1200/JCO.2018.77.8738"
response = requests.get(url)
filename.write_bytes(response.content)
```