# urllib.request.urlretrieve returns corrupt file (How to handle this kind of url?)

Tags: python, urllib

I want to download about 1000 pdf files from a web page.
Then I encountered this awkward pdf url format.
Both `requests.get()` and `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` don't work for me.

Usual pdf url looks like :

```
https://webpage.com/this_file.pdf
```

But this url is like :

```
https://gongu.copyright.or.kr/gongu/wrt/cmmn/wrtFileDownload.do?wrtSn=9000001&fileSn=1&wrtFileTy=01
```

So it doesn't have .pdf in url, and if you click on it, you can download it, But using python's `urllib`, you get corrupt file.

At first I thought it is redirected into some other url.
So I used `request.get(url, allow_retrieves=True)` option, 
the result is the same url as before..

```
filename = './novel/pdf1.pdf'
url = 'https://gongu.copyright.or.kr/gongu/wrt/cmmn/wrtFileDownload.do?wrtSn=9031938&fileSn=1&wrtFileTy=01'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

this code downloads corrupt pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using content field in the retrieved object.

```
filename = './novel1/pdf1.pdf'
url = . . .

object = requests.get(url)
with open('./novels/'+filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(t.content)
```

refered to this QnA ; [Download and save PDF file with Python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module)