# Python - Save A PDF file into Disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pdf

I have the code below which creates a `pdf` file in memory.

```
 pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(self.main_window.filename, extension='pdf')
```

I want to save that pdf file in disk so that I can view it. How will I do it in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download and save PDF file with Python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module

Comment: @PV8 It wasnt a duplicate. I dont have to download a pdf, I just have to save it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python

Comment: What is `type(pdf)`? If it is of type `<class 'bytes'>` then you can just use the standard file write method.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Yes it is of class bytes. how to do it? I tried  f = open("pdf.pdf", "w+")
        f.write(pdf)
        f.close()

Comment: @JustinEzequiel - Thank you. I made it with  f = open("pdf.pdf", "wb")  f.write(pdf) f.close() . You can put your answer at the answer section so that I can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `type(pdf)` is of type `<class 'bytes'>` then you can just do:

```
with open('yourfile.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdf)
```