# Save response.text as PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I have string representing a PDF that I'd like to save as a pdf file, my problem is that saving this string to a file results in a pdf with blank pages.

I've tried encoding the string as 'utf-8' and saving the bytes to a file but this results in the same issue.

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf'
response = requests.get(url)

with open('example.pdf', 'w') as f:
  f.write(response.text)
```

I'm aware that saving `response.content` is the correct way to save the pdf in the example above, but in my particular use case I only have access to the string

Comment: Have a look at this thread! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python

Comment: Why can't you use response.content? If you could you could open it using "wb" instead of "w" and write it and it would work perfectly for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download and save PDF file with Python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: As I said, I'm unable to access the content, I only have the text. My snipped above shows how to replicate the issue, but in my use case I'm getting the response text from elsewhere (not using the requests library)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using **fpdf** library.

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=response.text, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.output("output.pdf")
```

Reference: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/06/05/creating-pdfs-with-pyfpdf-and-python/

Docs: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I just tried this and received this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 122: ordinal not in range(256)`. The text I'm trying to save looks like this (first 200 characters): `%PDF-1.4\n%äüöß\n2 0 obj\n<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>\nstream\nx�=��\n\x021\x0cE����v\x11���0\x08\x0e�~��\x0f�\x00\x17���` i.e. it's the text of the actual PDF, not html

Answer (score 0):

From a link I posted before:

Use Pdfkit.

It creates pdf from html files. I chose it to create pdf in 2 steps from my Python Pyramid stack:

Rendering server-side with mako templates with the style and markup you want for you pdf document
Executing pdfkit.from_string(...) method by passing the rendered html as parameter.
This way you get a pdf document with styling and images supported.

You can install it as follows :

using pip

```
pip install pdfkit
```

You will also need to install wkhtmltopdf (on Ubuntu).

Comment: This won't work, the text I'm trying to save isn't html, it's the string of a pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import pdftotext

# Load your PDF
with open(r'C:\Users\Mahsa\Desktop\stack\dummy.pdf', "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
```

For saving text to pdf:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_xy(0, 0)
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt="Your text from ", border=0)
pdf.output(r'D:\pdf\test.pdf', 'F')
```

Comment: This loads the pdf as text, I'm trying to save a text representation of a PDF to a file

Comment: @bgordon I updated my answer, you can save text to pdf.