# how to get the text from pdf file linked to web page using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-crawler, pdfminer

I'm trying to use python 3 to get text data from pdf linked to webpage, and save it as csv file.

I've tried to get url of pdf files from webpage. Then after reading it, made attempt to get the text through pdfminer.

here's my code:

```
def PDFtoStringFromUrl(url):
    try:
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        retstr = StringIO()
        codec = 'utf-8'
        laparams = LAParams()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
        context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
        f = urlopen(url, context=context).read()
        fp = BytesIO(f)
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        password = ""
        maxpages = 0
        caching = True
        pagenos = set()
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp,
                                      pagenos,
                                      maxpages=maxpages,
                                      password=password,
                                      caching=caching,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
        fp.close()
        device.close()
        a = retstr.getvalue()
        retstr.close()
        return a.replace('\n', ' ').strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Read PDF Error :" + str(e))
        raise NotImplemented

pdf_url, content = []
url = 'https://hcss.nl/research?page={}'
for page_num in range(0, 16):
    response = requests.get(url.format(page_num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    list = []
    for link in soup.select('#visible-content > div > div.main-container.container-fluid.js-quickedit-main-content > section > div.region.region-content > div.views-element-container.form-group > div > div > div > div > div.col-sm-3.search-right.hidden-xs > div > a'):
        pdf_link = link.get('href')

        if pdf_link.lower().endswith('pdf'):
            if pdf_link.startswith('http'):
                list.append(pdf_link)
            else:
                list.append('https://hcss.nl' + pdf_link)
    pdf_url.extend(list)

    ## get pdf
    pdf_text = []
    for file in pdf_url:
        s = PDFtoStringFromUrl(file)
        s = "".join(s)
        pdf_text.append(s)
    content.extend(pdf_text)
```

but i've got following error message:

```
Read PDF Error :Literal required: <PDFStream(331): raw=68251, {'CIDSystemInfo': {'Ordering': b'Japan1', 'Registry': b'Adobe', 'Supplement': 6}, 'CMapName': /'UniJIS-UTF16-H', 'Filter': /'FlateDecode', 'Length': 68249, 'Type': /'CMap', 'WMode': 0}>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download and save PDF file with Python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow and welcome to python programming! You are hiding the original error by catching are reraising another error. You should remove the try-except structure and post the original error with (optionally) a piece of the stack trace. This will help others to identify the error.