# Why the page returns a text/html if is .pdf file?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a little issue automating the download of some files.

If a get the [link](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-981-13-2475-8.pdf) headers it returns a `'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'` and I need that returns the .pdf to get the name.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
req = requests.get(link)
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503412/download-and-save-pdf-file-with-python-requests-module

Comment: when I click on that link I get a CAPTCHA check, presumably your code is triggering the same because the site doesn't want you to automatically download all their content...