# How to download files in python with post request?

Tags: python

I am trying to download an export from an app automatically with python.
Here is my code:

```
export_url = 'https://....'
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
r = requests.post(export_url, data=payload)
print(r)
```

the response is 200 but the file is missing somehow
what is wrong?

edit:

this is my whole code:

```
import requests

URL = 'homepage_after_login'
LOGIN_URL = 'loginpage'

session = requests.session()

username = 'uname'
password = 'pass'
loginformtype = "value"
submit = "Sign+in"

login_data = {'username'        : username,
              'password'        : password,
              'login-form-type' : loginformtype,
              'submit'          : submit}

session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data)

req = session.get(URL)

export_url = 'https://....'
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
r = requests.post(export_url, data=payload)
print(r)
```

possibily it ignores the login part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download image using requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Comment: your code only gets the content in memory but never writes it to a file

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should take a look at the [documentation.](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response)

When you print `r`, you get the status code. (Well, not exactly, but the printed number is the status code.)

What you probably want to use is `r.text`:

> **text**
>
> Content of the response, in unicode.
>
> If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using `chardet`.
>
> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take
>   advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the
>   encoding, you should set `r.encoding` appropriately before accessing
>   this property.

Or `r.content`:

> **content**
>
> Content of the response, in bytes.