# Download file after POST form submission

Tags: python, http, post, get, python-requests

I am trying to download the file from [here](https://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/download/public_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2).

In Firefox, the link redirects me to a webpage where I have to log in with my credentials. After doing so, Firefox automatically prompts me to save the desired file with a pop-up windows.

I am trying to replicate that behavior with Python without success.

I've tried the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747033/how-to-download-files-in-python-with-post-request), namely

```py
import requests

session = requests.session()

url = "https://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/download/public_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2"

data= {'username': 'xxxxx', 'password':'xxxxxx'}

session.post(url, data=data)

response = requests.get("https://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/download/public_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2")

print(response.text)
```

**Insights from Firefox**

Using the Network tab from the Developer Mode, I have been able to see the following:

- The POST request, apart from `username` and `password` sends also an `execution` parameter, which seems to be very long hashed string. I don't know what this is or how to replicate this.

```
POST /cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fmetamap.nlm.nih.gov%2fdownload%2fpublic_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1
Host: utslogin.nlm.nih.gov
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 4900
Origin: https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fmetamap.nlm.nih.gov%2fdownload%2fpublic_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2
Cookie: TGC=exxxxxx; JSESSIONID=xxxxx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

- Afterwards, there is a GET request to the same address with a `ticket` parameter.

```
GET /download/public_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2?ticket=xxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: metamap.nlm.nih.gov
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fmetamap.nlm.nih.gov%2fdownload%2fpublic_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: MOD_AUTH_CAS_S=xxxxxx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

- Finally, another GET triggers the download.

```
GET /download/public_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1
Host: metamap.nlm.nih.gov
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fmetamap.nlm.nih.gov%2fdownload%2fpublic_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: MOD_AUTH_CAS_S=xxxxx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

In between all of this, cookies are set and read.

I don't know what information is useful. I'm putting here all that I can see.

Than you in advanced.

**EDIT:**

After more exploration I am trying to replicate the 3 request pattern seen in Mozilla/Chrome.

This is my code now:

```py
import requests

url_1 = "https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/login"
# url_2 = "https://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/download/public_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2"

params = {'service': 'https%3a%2f%2fmetamap.nlm.nih.gov%2fdownload%2fpublic_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2'}

data = {'username': 'xxxxx', 
'password':'xxxxx',
'execution': '1cb37c1a-141b-4891-b961-ea5c4b20deed_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',
'submit': 'LOGIN'}

r = requests.get(url_1, params = params)

print(r.headers)

print(r.cookies)

print(r.status_code)


headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1,
'Referer': 'https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov/cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fmetamap.nlm.nih.gov%2fdownload%2fpublic_mm_linux_main_2020.tar.bz2',
'Origin': 'https://utslogin.nlm.nih.gov',
'Host': 'utslogin.nlm.nih.gov',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es-CO;q=0.7,es-AR;q=0.6,es;q=0.5,it;q=0.',
'Content-Length': 4634}

r_2 = requests.post(url_1, data=data, cookies=r.cookies, params = params)

print("-----------------")

print(r_2.headers)

print(r_2.cookies)

print(r_2.status_code)
```

`execution` and `submit` are parameters also passed during the POST request. With the first `GET` I emulate the normal loading of the page, after which a cookie is given to me. Using that cookie and submitting the form, I expect to get back another `cookie` and a `ticket` with which to download the file. However, instead of getting this, what I see in output is the response header of another `GET` as is anything had happened.

By the way, to whomever wants to help me: the credentials from that site are acquired prior by registering and some hours may pass between registration and credential arrival.

Comment: Try using cookie.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?