# Python / BeautifulSoup Image Scraping Does Not Save Animated GIFs Correctly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, animated-gif

I have a piece of Python code that helps me with scraping some images from a website every morning - for a daily project I am responsible for. It all works fine and I get JPGs and PNGs with no issues. The problem is that animated GIFs most of the time get saved/downloaded as a static GIF. Sometimes it does save as animated but rarely.

Im not really familiar with BeautifulSoup, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or there is a limitation in the way BeautifulSoup handles animated GIFs.

Im using the kickstarter url just for testing purposes...

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

baseUrl = requests.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/peak-design/travel-tripod-by-peak-design')
soup = BeautifulSoup(baseUrl.text, 'html.parser')

allImgs = soup.findAll('img')

imgCounter = 1

for img in allImgs:
    newImg = img.get('src')

    # CHECK EXTENSION
    if '.jpg' in newImg:
        extension = '.jpg'
    elif '.png' in newImg:
        extension = '.png'
    elif '.gif' in newImg:
        extension = '.gif'

    imgFile = open(str(imgCounter) + extension, 'wb')
    imgFile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(newImg).read())
    imgCounter = imgCounter + 1
    imgFile.close()
```

Any help or insight on this issue would be most appreciated!!!

-S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download this GIF(dynamic) by Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534830/how-to-download-this-gifdynamic-by-python)

Comment: @DavidZemens Ya I read that thread but I'm confused on how to combine what they are doing with what I'm doing. The differences I see are these lines `imgFile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(newImg).read())` vs `f.write(requests.get(uri).content)` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what works for me...
Basically I need to grab the `data-src` from any file that is a GIF and not the `src` as I was doing for ALL images.

Here's the revised code:

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

baseUrl = requests.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/peak-design/travel-tripod-by-peak-design')
soup = BeautifulSoup(baseUrl.text, 'html.parser')

allImgs = soup.findAll('img')

imgCounter = 1

for img in allImgs:
    newImg = img.get('data-src')
    if newImg == None:
        newImg = img.get('src')

    #CHECK EXTENSION
    if '.jpg' in newImg:
        extension = '.jpg'
    elif '.png' in newImg:
        extension = '.png'
    elif '.gif' in newImg:
        extension = '.gif'

    imgFile = open(str(imgCounter) + extension, 'wb')
    imgFile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(newImg).read())
    imgCounter = imgCounter + 1
    imgFile.close()
```