# Correct way to handle mime types in a downloader

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I use the requests library in python to download an image file using http. I convert the received content to raw bytes using BytesIO in python and then use Pillow() to save this raw content as a jpeg file.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

rsp = requests.get(imageurl)
content_type_received = rsp.headers['Content-Type'] # mime type
binarycontent = BytesIO(rsp.content)
if content_type_received.startswith('image'): # image/jpeg, image/png etc
    i = Image.open(binarycontent)
    outfilename = os.path.join(outfolder,'myimg'+'.jpg')
    with open(outfilename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(rsp.content)
    rsp.close()
```

In the above code, I am forcing conversion to jpg irrespective of the mime type. This does not seem nice to me viscerally. Is there a standard way of handling the mime subtypes image/png, image/gif etc in python or the Pillow library?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure of what it is you're trying to do but this library [Python Magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) will allow you to examine file headers to interpret MIME types.

EDIT:
If you trust content type (you generally shouldn't), go ahead and name the file using that. if you don't use Python magic to interrogate the image type and then use that. The file you save is not being "converted" it is in what ever format was sent.

Comment: I am trying to save an image received through python requests which could be png, jpeg etc. I think it should not be transformed in this way abrubtly to jpeg.

Comment: This answer may be helpful also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests

Comment: You do not need to use Pillow if you are not going to do anything with the image object. Just inspect the first 1024 bytes of rsp.raw: `real_mime_type = magic.from_buffer(rsp.raw.read(1024), mime=True)` and decide what to do with the `rsp.content` (discard it or save it).