# Beautiful soup extract pic of the day

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would want to extract the picture of the day from the following webpage https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html using beautiful soup.

Could someone help me out with the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Please follow the guideline while asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . BTW can you please be more specific about "extract". Is that getting the linked? Save the image to your disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
pip install --upgrade html5lib
```

Then to get the img src url you can do this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
data = requests.get("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
img = soup.findAll("img")[0] # this link has only one image
src = "https://apod.nasa.gov"+img.attrs.get("src")
```

Remember dont ask to write code for you. first try and show us your effrot. This should be your last question like this.

To download the image you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/2956480) answer