# StringIO initial_value must be str, not Bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, stringio

Ok so i have this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import requests
from io import StringIO

url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/247096918923149313/34a66572b9339acdaa1dedbcb63bc90a.png?size=256"
response = requests.get(url)
pp = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))
pp.save("image1.png")

pp = Image.open("image2c.png").convert("LA")
pp.save("image2c.png")

background = Image.open("image1.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = Image.open("image2c.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = foreground.resize((256, 256), Image.BILINEAR)
background.paste(foreground, (125, 325), foreground)
background.show()
```

This returns the error: `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`

I can't see where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: try `pp = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`response` is binary data (`bytes`) and `Image` also expects some binary data.

So:

```
pp = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))
```

is injecting a text-based IO object in the middle: cannot convert bytes to text (and the next problem would be: cannot read text data into the image)

Fix:

```
from io import BytesIO
pp = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

EDIT: even better, use `Image.open(response.raw)` like answered here: [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)