# How to compress image and then upload it to AWS S3 bucket using FastAPI?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

Here is my code for uploading the image to AWS S3:

```
@app.post("/post_ads")
async def create_upload_files(files: list[UploadFile] = File(description="Multiple files as UploadFile")):
    main_image_list = []
    for file in files:
          s3 = boto3.resource(
             's3',
              aws_access_key_id =   aws_access_key_id,
               aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key
                            )
           bucket = s3.Bucket(aws_bucket_name)
           bucket.upload_fileobj(file.file,file.filename,ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"})
```

Is there any way to **compress the image size** and upload the image to a **specific folder** using `boto3`? I have this function for compressing the image, but I don't know how to integrate it into boto3.

```
         for file in files:
                im = Image.open(file.file)
                im = im.convert("RGB")
                im_io = BytesIO()
                im = im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=50)  
                
                s3 = boto3.resource(
                                's3',
                                aws_access_key_id =   aws_access_key_id,
                                aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key
                            )
                bucket = s3.Bucket(aws_bucket_name)
                bucket.upload_fileobj(file.file,file.filename,ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"})
```

**Update #1**

After following Chris's recommendation, my problem has been resolved:

Here is **Chris's solution**:

```
im_io.seek(0)
bucket.upload_fileobj(im_io,file.filename,ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"})
```

Comment: Chris I updated my question. I fixed corrupted image issue.  Right now I just want to  how I can compress image before upload it aws s3 bucket? I saw the answer but didn't understood properly.

Comment: @Chris can you please explain `bucket.upload_fileobj(im_io,...`? is it  `bucket.upload_fileobj(im,...`?

Comment: Chris I tried `bucket.upload_fileobj(im_io,..` but my image getting corrupted after uploading. I faced the similar issue   before. If I remove my image compressing code then my original image uploaded without any issue

Comment: @Chris yes exactly  it's zero. please see the full line  `bucket.upload_fileobj(im_io,file.filename,ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read", })`

Comment: @Chris I tried but still now zero size and can't view image from url.  I also updated my question

Comment: @ Chris now image is uploading also compressing   but can't view image from url. see the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yNNSWrBsYUALjaeamfFEjsmUYaplUVux/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Chris bro after adding `im_io.seek(0)` image is uploading and also compressing but can't view image from url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be saving the image bytes to a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) stream, which is never used, as you upload the original file object to the s3 bucket instead, as shown in this line of your code:

```py
bucket.upload_fileobj(file.file, file.filename, ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"})
```

Hence, you need to pass the `BytesIO` object to `upload_fileobj()` function, and **make sure to call** `.seek(0)` before that, in order to rewind the cursor  (or "file pointer") to the start of the buffer. The reason for calling `.seek(0)` is that `im.save()` method uses the cursor to iterate through the buffer, and when it reaches the end, it does not reset the cursor to the beginning. Hence, any future read operations would start at the end of the buffer. The same applies to reading from the original file, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804)—you would need to call `file.file.seek(0)`, if the file contents were read already and you needed to read from the `file` again.

Example on how to load the image into `BytesIO` stream and use it to upload the file/image can be seen below. Please remember to properly `close` the `UploadFile`, `Image` and `BytesIO` objects, in order to release their memory (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811351/17865804) as well).

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException
from PIL import Image
import io

# ...

try:        
    im = Image.open(file.file)
    if im.mode in ("RGBA", "P"): 
        im = im.convert("RGB")  
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    im.save(buf, 'JPEG', quality=50)
    buf.seek(0)
    bucket.upload_fileobj(buf, 'out.jpg', ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"})
except Exception:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
finally:
    file.file.close()
    buf.close()
    im.close()
```

As for the URL, using `ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"}` should work as expected and make your resource (file) publicly accessible. Hence, please make sure you are accessing the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

aws s3 sync s3://your-pics. for file in "$ (find. -name "*.jpg")"; do gzip "$file"; echo "$file"; done aws s3 sync. s3://your-pics --content-encoding gzip --dryrun This will download all files in s3 bucket to the machine (or ec2 instance), compresses the image files and upload them back to s3 bucket.

This should help you.