# aws s3 why my image not available publicly after upload?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

my image is uploading on s3 bucket and I added parameter `ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"}` but my image not available for public view. here is my code:

```
       s3 = boto3.resource(
      's3',
       aws_access_key_id =   "" ,
       aws_secret_access_key = ""
       )
       bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket_name')  
       im_io.seek(0) 
       unique_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
       bucket.upload_fileobj(im_io,'ads_image/'+blog_title+unique_uuid +file.filename,ExtraArgs={"ACL":"public-read"})
       upload_file_url = "https://{'MY_url'}.s3.us-east-3.amazonaws.com/ads_image/"+blog_title+unique_uuid+file.filename
```

I also added my bucked policy and enabled public my s3 bucket. here is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy16****",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "my ip"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why would it be available publicly, if you `Deny` it in your policy?

Comment: It's will deny only s3 put object if request not coming from my server and will not deny public view

Comment: I aslo manually uploaded few image and those images publicly available.

Comment: Is **S3 Block Public Access** turned OFF for the bucket? Specifically, the options that relate to ACLs? Also, do you know whether the bucket was created with `Object Ownership = ACLs disabled`? You can check this in the Permissions tab.

Comment: John Rotenstein yes Block Public Access turned OFF  but when trying to `Ownership = ACLs disabled` getting this error. see the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/13BWh1i1QIGQzWKIPR3vlY2c4Zpd7EULo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @boyenec The policy has `s3:GetObject` as well, not only put.

Comment: @Marcin what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems after keep all images inside an single directory before I was keeping theme like `/main_folder/sub_folder`

now all images I keeping theme inside an single directory and my problem solved.

Comment: Please remember to `close` the in-memory bytes buffer afterwards, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815575/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811351/17865804), in order to release the memory.