# How to upload uploaded file in s3 bucket using FASTAPI (Unable to upload (uploaded excel file from FASTAPI) in s3 bucket)

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I got error when uploading uploaded file in s3 bucket using FASTAPI.

```
@app.post('/uploadedfile/')
def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
 
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
    df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(file.file.read()))
    data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    file.file.close()
    object = s3.Object('bucket_name',file.filename)
    result =object.put(Body=file.filename)
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

Comment: See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815575/17865804) as well.