# Issue with Uploading PDFs to AWS S3 Using FastAPI and Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

I am facing a problem while attempting to upload PDF files to an AWS S3 Bucket using FastAPI and the boto3 library. The files seem to upload successfully, but when downloading the same PDFs from S3, they appear completely blank. Not able to understand where the issue is coming from below code.

```
@router.post('/upload', tags=["Upload Files"])
async def upload_file(
        Type: str = Form(...),
        Id: str = Form(None),
        dept: str = Form(...),
        PolicyType=Form(...),
        file: UploadFile = File(...),
        userId: str = Depends(get_current_user)
):

    fileObj, fileName = validate_post_request(file)
    content = await file.read()
    
    

    filePath = f"{Type}/{Id}/{uniqueId}"

    # Store data in S3
    fileObj.seek(0)
    s3Response = upload_to_s3(content,S3_BUCKET_NAME, filePath)
    if not s3Response:
        logger.error('Unable to upload file')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Unable to upload file, try again later")

    response = {
        'error': False,
        'message': 'Uploaded successfully',
    }
    return response



def upload_to_s3(file_obj: bytes, bucket: str, object_name: str) -> bool:
    try:
        s3_client.put_object(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Key=object_name,
            Body=file_obj
        )
    except Exception as err:
        return False
    return True
```

I tried with generating pre-signed URL and then attaching pdf file to it , but result is same its completely blank on s3

Comment: Please have a look at the following answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815575/17865804)

Comment: No, Still same issue is facing by using ur approach

Comment: May be you should add code for upload_to_s3 also

Comment: I edit above code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, validate_post_request() function is just checking whether the given file name has ".pdf" extension or not using the python .split() method. Commented out the 'validate_post_request()' function then tried again but facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with your code but I've done something like this

```
@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_fileobj(file.file, bucket_name, file_name)
```