# how can I upload image to this website with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

Every time I try, I got error in instruction of the find_element, can someone try upload an image to this specific web site: https://www.custojusto.pt/ai/form/0
and let me know how I can solve this?

```
def upload():
    driver.get('https://www.custojusto.pt/ai/form/0')
    #time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_name('image').send_keys("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pzTMUV7AL._SY300_.jpg")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload()
```

Comment: What error do you get? Include the traceback in your question

Comment: In https://www.custojusto.pt/ai/form/0 site we have 2 input which have image - tag name . which one you are using?

Comment: "Arpit Solanki" here is the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\workspace\ROBOT\upload.py", line 18, in <module>
    upload()
  File "C:\Users\abc\workspace\ROBOT\upload.py", line 15, in upload
    driver.find_element_by_name('image').send_keys("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pzTMUV7AL._SY300_.jpg")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 349, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})

Comment: "Ankur Singh" I only can see one input to upload image this one: <input type="file" name="image" class="fixed" id="up" title="Clique para adicionar uma imagem">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can upload images using urls i believe. You need to download them manually and then upload it. You can download the image using approach discussed on below thread

[How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Also your upload part is in a IFrame so you need to switch to Iframe first

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
def upload():
    driver.get('https://www.custojusto.pt/ai/form/0')
    #time.sleep(10)

    driver.switch_to.frame("image-upload")
    driver.find_element_by_name('image').send_keys("/tmp/aws.png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload()
    driver.quit()
```

I tested the above code and it works great for me. Note once the image is uploaded , if you need to upload another image, use `driver.switch_to.frame("image-upload")` again as a new frame gets created and old isn't valid anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much, now is working from the disk drive, as that website can get links and allowed the receipt of the link in place of the file in I thought I could also do it with selenium But in fact with the link selenium always gives error.. But in fact this understanding of frame exchange was crucial to me.