# Python Reddit API have URLs in variable but need to sort them

Tags: python, reddit, praw

So I'm using PRAW, a python wrapper for reddit api (http://praw.readthedocs.io/en to find out more), and I have managed to print the URL's of my latest upvoted posts.

```
# start subreddit instance
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('dankmemes')

print("\n -> Current Subreddit: ")
print(subreddit.display_name)
redditor2 = reddit.redditor('me')
for upvoted in reddit.redditor('Kish_v').upvoted():
    print(upvoted.url)
```

This outputs a long list of imgur URLs etc. However, I want to be able to download those images to a folder and then reupload them as a sort of scraper.
So I have got to the point where `upvoted.url` holds my URLs but would the best way to do the above be to put the links into an "array" and then download those images individually? - How would I go around doing this, sorry I am fairly new to python as I came from PHP to use this well documented API.

Thank you,
Kish

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `requests` module, this SO question should get you pointed in the right direction with downloading the URLs you have on hand. I can't comment on the reuploading half.
[How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)