# Requests.get returning incorrect characters for XML string

Tags: xml, python-2.7, python-requests, elementtree

I'm attempting to collect some geocodes from the geocoder.ca API using requests.get that returns the data in XML format.

For the most part I've been able to encode as I need to and escape certain characters (&) so that when I attempt to import this data into an Element (using the ElementTree from the xml module) it doesn't complain.

But for one particular lat/long set, the address that's returned contains less than symbols (<) which generates the 'not well-formed (invalid token)' error when attempting to parse the xml string.

Looking up the actual address the street name contains a ë character which for whatever reason is translated to 'A<<' in the response content:

```
<geodata>

    <latt>45.644743</latt>
    <longt>-76.033414</longt>
    <city>La PAache</city>
    <prov>QC</prov>
    <postal>J0X2W0</postal>
    <stnumber>11</stnumber>
    <staddress>RaphaA<<l CH</staddress>

    <inlatt>45.6464</inlatt>
    <inlongt>-76.0352</inlongt>
    <distance>0.082</distance><NearRoad>Raphael CH</NearRoad>
    <NearRoadDistance>0.083</NearRoadDistance>

    <TimeZone>America/Toronto</TimeZone>     <AreaCode>819</AreaCode>

</geodata>
```

Obviously this is not correct, I have had no trouble with any other accented characters so I'm not sure why this one in particular is tripping me up.

Here is the code I'm using to grab and parse the XML data that's returned from requests.get:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

url = "http://geocoder.ca"
xmlFile = open('xmlFile.xml', 'w')

latt = 45.6464
longt = -76.0352

params = {'latt': latt, 'longt' : longt, 'reverse': 1, 'geoit': 'XML'}
r = requests.get(url, params = params)

xmlFile.write(r.content)

tree = ElementTree.fromstring((r.content.replace('&', '&amp;')))
```

I could just try and find a way to escape those two characters, but I would still have a wonky address that would no longer make any sense (which I don't want)

If anybody has any insights on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that service is clearly broken. My first thought was, if XML does not work properly, switch to another output format like CSV or JSON, but that either does not work or triggers server errors. I wonder if it would make sense to simply pick another geocoding service instead of trying to work around the bugs of this one.

Comment: On an unrelated note, do not use text mode files to write XML. When you want to write an HTTP response to an XML file, pick one of the ways shown here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests - it's essential that you write in binary mode.

Comment: Out of ~35000 lats and longs I used only about 5 of them ended up like the one above (it's just that particular accent for whatever reason) and the geocoder I'm using is honestly one of the better ones as I need to grab postal code's and it's far far more accurate than any other geocoder I've used (Google especially). Also thanks, I'll take a look at that link you sent and edit my code as neccessary :)

Comment: I see. Then I guess you would be a good person for contacting them and telling them that their stuff is broken. :) In any case, if you must use them, I suggest you save the file as shown in the other thread and use [HTML tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) in XML mode to fix the file for you, I'm confident it can iron out these errors. That way there's going to be way less hair-pulling than trying to write that code yourself. After cleaning, you can use ElementTree to load the XML file. Tidy is available as a standalone program and also as a Python package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytidylib

Comment: That's true, I think I will contact them. Hopefully you're right and it'll help get rid of the errors I'm dealing with, otherwise I'll wait to hear back from the website mods to see if they can fix anything. You provided me good info to improve my code so thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope this gets fixed quickly. It's actually a pretty hair-raising bug.