# Open image after BytesIO

Tags: python

I would like to get a photo from my url. Trying to create it ,then use `.get()` and convert it into :`BytesIO()`

```
 img = Image.fromarray(srcData) 
 fp = 'https://telegram.org/new.png'
 response = requests.get(fp)
 f = BytesIO(response.content)
 f.seek(0)
 f=Image.open(f)
```

Why do I get an error, which is:

> cannot identify image file _io.bytesio

Then try to send it:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=f)
```

Comment: Maybe something from this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873

Comment: to load an image from url, i use this code. https://pastebin.com/raw/5fwUCFJp

Comment: @Cole           thank you! It helped. But can I ask smth?

Comment: @Cole           It's a bout a telegram bot...