# How to extract a labelled dataset from a JSON API? (NLM RxImage)

Tags: python, json, database, api

I am hoping to do some image classification on pills.

The National Library of Medicine has an pill image database, [RxImage website](https://lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/rximage-api). It has an API which you can retrieve images with specific requests in the form of JSON files. ([Sample API request builder](https://rximage.nlm.nih.gov/index/visualizer/)).

I want to download the labelled image dataset in order to do some image classification on it in python. Is there a way to do this? (preferably in python)

Comment: Just for clarification, are you refering to the `imageUrl` key? Like these, [here](https://imgur.com/a/irD2V)?

Comment: Basically, I want to download all of the images, but also have the data of their colour, shape, imprint that is in the respective JSON files.

Comment: Seems like a pretty simple thing. Send off the request, loop through all the JSON grabbing all necessary info. Then grab the `imageUrl` and do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21595698/6771714) with it.

Comment: How do I send a JSON request that gets every image in the database?

Comment: Look into the `requests` library. And just look around SO about how to send HTTP requests. There are hundreds of posts.