# How to save or download an image that I get in a request -- Python

Tags: python, save, python-requests

So, I am requesting a URL that actually brings a picture, nothing else, you type the URL, click "enter" and it gets you a picture.

Now, I want to save that picture into a file in a desired path by using python but I am not succeding.

Can you help me?

```
Picture_request = requests.get(Photo_URL)
```

Where to go from there?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? (hint: how would you save your response's body to file if it was json, html or plain text ?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import requests

picture_request = requests.get("https://example.com/picture/image.jpg")
if picture_request.status_code == 200:
    with open("image.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(picture_request.content)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just solved it like minutes before reading your answer but yeah, thats exactly what I did.

Comment: Posting comment on behalf of [@Burrito_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6088957)

`import requests, os

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
reg_url = 'https://mediacdn.99acres.com/8065/16/161316171M-1550756165.jpeg' test_path = os.path.join('/path/to/Desktop/img', 'cat.jpeg')

Picture_request = requests.get(reg_url) if Picture_request.status_code == 200: with open(test_path, 'wb') as f: f.write(Picture_request.content)`

This is not saving the image.