# Python Scrape Images From a Slideshow

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape images from the home page of my [school's website](http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/). But the catch is that these images are present in a slideshow. There are 9 images in total in the slideshow and I want to scrape all of them. I have no clue how I have to go about it, because all I can do with `requests` is to scrape the first image of it. And I don't want to use `selenium` because it is very slow. How can I scrape all images from the slideshow just by using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S: I know that I have to provide the code that I have written so far, but the problem is that I haven't tried out anything so far as I really have no idea how to go about it, because this is the first time I am scraping images from a slideshow, so please forgive me. Plus, I already went through [the answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554056/need-help-scraping-images-from-a-slideshow-with-bs4-python), but I didn't know how to implement the answer in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 9 images in the slider, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.select('#rev_slider_2_1 img'):
    print(img['src'])
```

Prints:

```
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/banner-4.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/banner-2.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/banner-7.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/bannerfour.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bannerseven.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bannerfives-1.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/banner-5.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bannereight.jpg
http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/banner-6.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.buddingmindsinternationalschool.com/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".rev-slidebg"):
    img_name = tag['src'].split('/')[-1]

    with open(img_name, "wb") as f:
        req = requests.get(tag['src'])
        f.write(req.content)
```