# How to display image from API response in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: image, jupyter-notebook, png, ipywidgets, azure-maps

I have an Azure Maps API call in a Jupyter Notebook that returns a map tile in .png format. The call works great, but I can't figure out how to display it as an image rather than as binary text.

**- API Call:**

```
import requests
from ipywidgets import Image

url = "https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png"

querystring = {
    "api-version":"1.0",
    "subscription-key":"<myRedactedAPIkey>",
    "layer":"basic",
    "zoom":"5",
    "center":"-122.3950336,47.566848",
    "height":"600",
    "width":"600",
    "pins":"default||-121.95066667 45.9135|-121.062 46.707",
    "format":"png",
    "path":"ra300||-122.3950336 47.566848"
}

payload = ""
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

**Results in:**

```
�PNG

IHDRX�f��sRGB���gAMA���a    pHYs���o�d��IDATx^��wt,K~�  �2ÕYqGg4+�iGsVgGg5Z�ќ]IT�Rs9\J䈤4r$r%�a���nv������}��wͻ������{[�By�20U\�6��@T"
��
�A�E��ֵ���|�%۶��O�N�#���dX��F��Y�p����y�l3�T�8;�Y�p�O҉#�վ8���yf����+5.����@0���q���Jތ�k��(�5�О���u���gBl�=�E���@�J����m=f�k&h��^��Z��Ms��̊\�J���if��C��:2_ <etc.>
```

**Want:**

[image]

Any advice? Thank you.

**EDIT2:** Here is the query that works. Thanks for your assistance everyone.

```
import requests
from IPython.display import Image, display

url = "https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png"
payload = ""
querystring = {
        "api-version":"1.0",
        "subscription-key":"<myApiKeyRedacted>",
        "format":"png",
        "layer":"basic",
        "zoom":"5",
        "center":"-122.3950336,47.566848",
        "height":"600",
        "width":"600",
        "pins":"default||-121.95066667 45.9135|-121.062 46.707",
        "path":"ra300000||-122.3950336 47.566848"
    }
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

r = requests.get(url,data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring, stream=all)

display(Image(r.content))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `response.raw` instead of text? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests).

Comment: Adding `response.raw` in lieu of `print(response.text)` results in `<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse at 0x7f0f4752df98>` but no .png.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what ended up working:
Appears a combo of `stream=all`, `Ipython.display` and `.content` did the trick.

```
import requests
from IPython.display import Image, display

url = "https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png"
payload = ""
querystring = {
        "api-version":"1.0",
        "subscription-key":"<myApiKeyRedacted>",
        "format":"png",
        "layer":"basic",
        "zoom":"5",
        "center":"-122.3950336,47.566848",
        "height":"600",
        "width":"600",
        "pins":"default||-121.95066667 45.9135|-121.062 46.707",
        "path":"ra300000||-122.3950336 47.566848"
    }
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

r = requests.get(url,data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring, stream=all)

display(Image(r.content))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `response.text` seems to be a valid PNG image and you are using ipywidgets `Image`, did you try to use this?

```
widgets.Image(
    value=response.text,
    format='png',
    width=300,
    height=400,
)
```

Comment: Hm. Bolting that on to the end results in the same binary text output.

Comment: Can you try with this: `display(Image(BytesIO(r.content)))` ? (BytesIO comes `from io import BytesIO`)