# How to solve cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make a python script to take a screenshots of subdomains automatically when I give it a list of subdomains in text file.

First I learnt python basics then started searching for how to do this
when I came to this code:

```py
import requests

BASE = 'https://render-tron.appspot.com/screenshot/'
url = 'https://www.google.com'
path = 'target.jpg'
response = requests.get(BASE + url, stream=True)
# save file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/7665691
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in response:
            file.write(chunk)
```

But, as I said before, I want to give it a list of subdomains and check it one by one,
so I edited this code to be:

```
import requests

BASE = 'https://render-tron.appspot.com/screenshot/'
url = open('s.txt','r')
path = 'target.jpg'
response = requests.get(BASE + url, stream=True)
# save file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/7665691
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in response:
            file.write(chunk)
```

But when I ran it it give me this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = requests.get(BASE + url, stream=True)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects
```

and this is the code I ran:

```
import requests

BASE = 'https://render-tron.appspot.com/screenshot/'
url = open('s.txt','r')
path = 'target.jpg'
response = requests.get(BASE + url, stream=True)
# save file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/7665691
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in response:
            file.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

BASE = 'https://render-tron.appspot.com/screenshot/'
url = 'https://www.google.com'
path = 'target.jpg'
response = requests.get(BASE + url, stream=True)
# save file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/7665691
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in response:
            file.write(chunk)
```

The code above is for getting just a photo from a url and saving it `target.jpg`. But what I understand is, what you are trying to do is,

You will have have something like

```
url1
url2
..
```

in a file, and you want to get

```
https://render-tron.appspot.com/screenshot/url1
https://render-tron.appspot.com/screenshot/url2
...
```

and save it in your computer.

The way you can do this is using the following code.

```
import requests
import os

BASE = 'https://render-tron.appspot.com/screenshot/'
# open the file that you have all the url's in read mode
f = open("urls.txt",'r')
# read all the url and put them in an array. 
urls = f.readlines()

# maintain a count for naming screenshot. Because if we save all images in in target.jpg
# we will end up getting only one image at after the code is executed. Because same file 
# will be overridden over and over again. Instead we plan to save them in 
# screenshot_1.jpg, screenshot_2.jpg etc. 
count = 0
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(BASE + url, stream=True)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # make the path for saving the image and store it it target_path
        target_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'screenshot_%d.jpg' % (count))
        with open(target_path, 'wb') as file:
            for chunk in response:
                file.write(chunk)
        # increase the count of files that has been saved
        count += 1
```

The expected behavior of this code will be,
If you have a file named `urls.txt` with urls

```
url1
url2
```

after running this code, you will have two screenshots named `screenshot_1.jpg` and `screenshot_2.jpg` with screenshot of `url1` and `url2`

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it makes no sense to try to combine a string and a file object.

Did you mean to access the *contents* of the file, rather than the *file object* itself?

If so, use this:

```
url = open('s.txt','r').read().strip()
```