# Downloading multiple files with requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, python-requests

Currently im facing following problem:

I have 3 download links in a list. Only the last file in the list is downloaded completely.
The others have a file size of one kilobyte.

Code:

```
from requests import get

def download(url, filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        response = get(url, stream=True)
        file.write(response.content)

for link in f:
    url = link
    split_url = url.split("/")
    filename = split_url[-1]
    filename = filename.replace("\n", "")
    download(url,filename)
```

The result looks like this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbY2r.png)

How do I make sure that all files are downloaded correctly?
All links are direct download links.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I discovered it only happens when I read the links from the .txt

If I create the list in python like this:

```
links = ["http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip",
            "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip",
            "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"]
```

... the problem doesnt appear.

reproduceable example:

```
from requests import get

def download(url, filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        response = get(url, stream = True)
        file.write(response.content)

f = open('links.txt','r')
for link in f:
    url = link
    split_url = url.split("/")
    filename = split_url[-1]
    filename = filename.replace("\n", "")
    download(url,filename)
```

content of links.txt:

```
http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip
http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip
http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip
```

Comment: In `download` when you print/inspect the content and the filename are they correct?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't try [this example in the docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Comment: 1: Filenames are correct for all 3 files. Only the content of file 3 is correct. The other files seem to be empty

2,3: I tried those, same issue :( 

When I switch the links in the list I still have the same problem - only the last file is downloaded correctly

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

url = url.replace("\n", "")

solved it!