# Error Opening Downloaded File from a Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

The code below downloads the pictures as .png filetype to my computer. However, when I try to open the images, the image viewer says: "It looks like we don't support this file format". I used another app to open the image and the problem persisted. It seems that the files are downloaded as 'bytes object' instead of as images..

```
import csv
import requests

with open('rlth.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(file.read(1024))
    file.seek(0)  # Rewind.
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    if has_header:
        next(reader)  # Skip header row.
    csvrows = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvrows:
        filename = row[0]
        url = row[2]
        print(url)
        result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            image = result.raw.read()
            open("{}.png".format(filename),"wb").write(image)
```

[image: rlth.csv]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests

Comment: i have tried several ways suggested there, but they don't seem to work for me.