# Save downloaded images with python into a local folder

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, save

I use the following code to scrape image url from a website. What I try to achieve next is to save urls that end with '.jpg' into a local folder which can be the location of the py code.
I manage to scrape and access urls and to create a folder in that location but I don't know how to save them.
This is my code, any ideas are highly appreciated

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:

from urllib.request import urlretrieve
else:
# if Not Python 3
from urllib import urlretrieve

site = 'https://www.amazon.de/dp/B077S8N26F'
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/image_folder/'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

img_tags = soup.find_all('img')
urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]
for url in urls:
print(url)
#only the links that end with .jpg
images = [im for im in urls if im.endswith(".jpg")]
print(images)
for im in images:
   #here is the missing part that saves urls into the folder created
```

Answer (score 1):

For each of your entries in `images`, that'll be the URI/URL of an image file.

To get the image, you need to make a separate HTTP request to get it. You can do this with `python-requests`

This existing answer should help you along the way without repeating it: [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)