# Discord.py error, PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I'm making a discord bot that sends a message whenever someones changes their avatar. It downloads their previous avatar and the new avatar, and joins them together, but I'm getting this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_user_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "bot.py", line 40, in on_user_update
images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['originalAvatar.png', 'updatedAvatar.png']]
File "bot.py", line 40, in <listcomp>
images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['originalAvatar.png', 'updatedAvatar.png']]
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2959, in open
"cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'originalAvatar.png'
```

This is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_user_update(before, after):
if before.avatar != after.avatar:
    mencao = after.mention
    channel = bot.get_channel(zzzzzzzzzzzzz)
    authorId = after.id
    tempo = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    originalFile = before.avatar_url_as(format='png', static_format='webp', size=128)
    updatedFile = after.avatar_url_as(format='png', static_format='webp', size=128)

    r = requests.get(originalFile, allow_redirects=True)
    open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content)
    s = requests.get(updatedFile, allow_redirects=True)
    open('updatedAvatar.png', 'wb').write(s.content)

    images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['originalAvatar.png', 'updatedAvatar.png']]
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    total_width = sum(widths)
    max_height = max(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

    x_offset = 0
    for im in images:
        new_im.paste(im, (x_offset, 0))
        x_offset += im.size[0]

    new_im.save('test.png')

    file = discord.File("test.png", filename="image.png")
    embed = discord.Embed(name="title", description=f"\U0001F5BC {mencao} **alterou o avatar**", color=0xe12674)
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"ID do usuário: {authorId} • {tempo}")

    await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)

    if os.path.exists(f"originalAvatar.png"):
        os.remove(f"originalAvatar.png")
    if os.path.exists(f"updatedAvatar.png"):
        os.remove(f"updatedAvatar.png")
    if os.path.exists("test.png"):
        os.remove("test.png")
```

I'm running the python file on heroku btw, how do I fix this?

UPDATE:
I've replaced
`open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content)` with

```
 with open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content) as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

but now it gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_user_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lucas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 
343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/lucas/bot/bot.py", line 36, in on_user_update
with open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content) as f:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

and here is the `on_message` part of the code:

```
 @bot.event
 async def on_message(message):
 mensagem = message.content
 if mensagem.startswith("$avatar") and hasNumbers(mensagem) == False:
     nome = message.author.name
     avatar = message.author.avatar_url_as(size=2048)
     r = requests.get(avatar, allow_redirects=True)
     with open('Avatar.gif', 'wb').write(r.content) as f:
         r.raw.decode_content = True
         shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: I suspect that if you view the contents of `originalAvatar.png` in a hex editor, it doesn't actually contain valid PNG data. Also you're not closing either of the open files so that could be an issue. You should use `with open`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Also you're not necessarily downloading images correctly; this looks different than your implementation. You're not using `r.raw` or `r.raw.decode_content`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests

Comment: I have replaced ```open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content)``` with ```with open(originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content) as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)``` and it works, *but* now it says ```File "/home/lucas/bot/bot.py", line 83, in on_message
    with open('Avatar.gif', 'wb').write(r.content) as f:
AttributeError: __enter__```

Comment: Sorry if my markdown is wonky, I'm new to this

Comment: Just put the updated info into your post so it's formatted properly, comments aren't meant for large blocks of code.

Comment: Also that error is from `on_message` which you didn't include the code of here. Seems like a separate issue entirely but I can't be sure unless you post the relevant code and the entire error.

Comment: My bad, I copied the wrong thing, but that error is also occuring on ```on_member_update```

Comment: The line `with open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content) as f:` is wrong. You just want `with open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb') as f:`, and then put `f.write(r.content)` inside that block.

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'll post my suggestions as an answer so you can upvote/accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines have a couple of issues:

```
r = requests.get(originalFile, allow_redirects=True)
open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

For one, it does not close the file `originalAvatar.png`. The `with open` statement should be used to avoid this issue. Secondly, it's not writing the actual raw binary data of the image to the file correctly. There are multiple ways to do this (see [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)), so I'll show just one possible method, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests):

```
r = requests.get(originalFile, allow_redirects=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True
with f = open('originalAvatar.png', 'wb'):
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```