# Python: convert request.content to image

Tags: python, python-requests, type-conversion, httprequest, imagedownload

I'm developing python code to save images from an api call.

My code is the following:

```
r = requests.get(urlGetPhoto, headers=h, stream=True)
```

After this call i obtain the image in in formats byte inside **r.content**.
Printing the content with postman I see that it is composed in the following way

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4...A/9k=" alt="Image"/>
```

I tried to convert it to image in several ways, but no ine gave me a readable image.
How can I perform this conversion to save the content?

Comment: pls try this (resource)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests], if none of those worked, pls share the URL of the image.

Comment: Hi, I find the solution cutting off the excess parts of data such as <img src=" and " alt="Image"/> . Then with the answers of the suggested question I solved. Thanks you