# How can I screenshot a website using R?

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

So I'm not 100% sure this is possible, but I found [a good solution in Ruby](https://github.com/ezkl/capit) and in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-image-of-a-website-using-python), so I was wondering if something similar might work in R.

Basically, given a URL, I want to render that URL, take a screenshot of the rendering as a .png, and save the screenshot to a specified folder.  I'd like to do all of this on a headless linux server.

Is my best solution here going to be running `system` calls to a tool like [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/), or does there exist an R-based toolset that will help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can take screenshots using Selenium:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs")
remDr <- rD[['client']]
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")
remDr$screenshot(file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"))
shell.exec(tf) # on windows
remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
```

---

In earlier versions, you were able to do:

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")
remDr$screenshot(file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"))
shell.exec(tf) # on windows
```

Comment: You can use `browseURL(tf)` to view screenshot on Linux

Comment: The function `startServer()` is defunct in version 1.7.1. They say "The
recommended way to run a selenium server is via Docker. Alternatively
see the RSelenium::rsDriver function."

Answer (score 11):

I haven't tested it, but this open source project seems to do exactly that: https://github.com/wch/webshot

It is a easy as:

```
library(webshot)
webshot("https://www.r-project.org/", "r.png")
```

Comment: I tried this and got error with curl unable to authenticate

Comment: RSelenium seems to be defunct.