# Automatically take and download a screenshot in Shiny

Tags: r, screenshot, shiny, leaflet

I would like users of my R Shiny app to be able to download screenshots of the browser automatically. I am displaying a Leaflet map as well as some information in different tab panels.

Is there a R package that allows for this functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418765/how-can-i-screenshot-a-website-using-r ?

Comment: @Spacedman I see that question is related, but I am not sure it is a duplicate. On the OP's shiny site the user may have zoomed in to someplace on the map and interacted with some widgets and so on. I don't think the answer you linked to would capture that in the screenshot.

Comment: I think that's the best answer you're going to get for doing it with R. Just ask the users to install a browser screenshot plugin and click the button.