# R: Screenshot of you Desktop

Tags: r, imagemagick, screenshot, snapshot

Is there a function or package to take a screenshot of your desktop?

I understand there are packages like webshot, RSelenium, and SeleniumPipes to take screenshots of the browser, but I'd like a way in R to interact with my OS's native screen capture utility (or ImageMagick's Import function) to take a screen capture of my desktop at command and save it locally.

Given comments, there may be a way to do this with a `system` call, but cannot seem to find any examples of this anywhere.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: LEAVE COMMENTS DOWNVOTERS

Comment: I would like to take a screenshot of my desktop and locate the position of an element on this screenshot. The first step would be to take a screenshot. It is kind of computer vision....Please let me know if you need further information. thank you

Comment: ... Does it need to be an R package?  There are lots of screenshot programs and plenty that offer command line capabilities which you could call via `system`.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418765/how-can-i-screenshot-a-website-using-r

Comment: @Dason, yes it would be great if it was in R.

Comment: @Prince Modi, yes i already saw this post but this is limited to your webbrowser. Thank you.

Comment: @Khagay - I suspect the downvotes are because the question is not about programming, it doesn't ask a specific question, it's not a reproducible error, it shows no research effort, and, it's not an appropriate question for StackOverflow (see close reason)

Comment: @SymbolixAU I would love it if the downvoters would of said that