# Screenshot of a website with Python (Windows)

Tags: python, browser, screenshot, html

**How to take a screenshot of a website with Python, Windows environment ?**

---

Remarks :

- The question of taking a screenshot of a website with Python has been highly discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-image-of-a-website-using-python) but most of the solutions only work for Mac like `webkit2png` (see the discussion [here](https://github.com/paulhammond/webkit2png/issues/9) about portability and also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/713975/1422096)) or Linux
- The only half-working solution I've found is :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser.get('http://www.example.com')
  browser.save_screenshot('test.png')
  ```

  it works 50% of the time, but when doing it for 100 pages, in a loop, it always stops / is stuck / after 10 or 15 or 25 pages. Even if I `time.sleep(...)`, etc.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when it stops/crashes?

Comment: No error, it's just stuck (like if the browser was still waiting for hours for the page to load)

Comment: Thanks, what about if you use chrome instead of firefox?

Comment: Does the website allow for subsequent requests? It may be helpful to see the URLs and learn about the sleeps you inserted.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it a lot in the meantime, and I corrected my question : it's not a crash, it's only "stuck".

Comment: The question is : isn't there *another system* than having the code to launch Firefox / Chrome and then asking the browser to take the screenshot? It is a bit dirtyish. Wouldn't it possible to have a 100% command-line solution (not relying on an external browser) ?

Comment: You do not employ an external browser, but you will have to employ a browser engine that does the JavaScript execution and the HTML/CSS rendering for you. This is the headless browser, in your case Selenium. If you don't like Selenium, you can use e.g. PhantomJS, but without a packaged browser engine...

Answer (score 1):

I created a library called pywebcapture that wraps selenium that will do just that:

```
pip install pywebcapture
```

Once you install with pip, you can do the following to easily get full size screenshots:

```
# import modules
from pywebcapture import loader, driver

# load csv with urls
csv_file = loader.CSVLoader("csv_file_with_urls.csv", has_header_bool, url_column, optional_filename_column)
uri_dict = csv_file.get_uri_dict()

# create instance of the driver and run
d = driver.Driver("path/to/webdriver/", output_filepath, delay, uri_dict)
d.run()
```

Enjoy!

https://pypi.org/project/pywebcapture/